# Add script defining paths to .Rprofile

Tags: r, path

I am working on a project where I was hoping we'd be able to set file paths using the .Rprofile. I wrote a script that defines paths for specific users and since we're using `renv` and that puts an activate script into the profile anyways, I just added my `paths.R` script after that in the .Rprofile.

When I asked a colleague to open the .Rproj file to open the project, I thought it would run `renv/activate.R` and my `paths.R` script, but they're not seeing their defined paths, only mine. Am I missing something?

```
# contents of my .Rprofile
source("renv/activate.R")
source("paths.R")
```

```
# contents of path.R
if (Sys.info()["user"] == "francisco"){
  data_dir <- 
    'path/to/data'
}
# etc
```

Any advice on workflow is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hard to diagnose. But really, rather than hard-code different user configurations in the same file, why not have one file per user? Meaning, each user has their own `paths.R` file that they keep locally, with only their settings. In fact, this would usually not be an R file anyway, but rather a JSON, or CSV, or something along those lines.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but in a shared working drive, defining specific paths allows us to "just make it work" across mac and windows users.

Comment: Sharing configuration between different people on a shared drive strikes me as a very bad idea. I would (strongly) recommend storing the configuration in each person’s configuration directory instead — separate from the code (which can be shared, if it’s not edited). on Windows, that’s in `%LocalAppData%`, and you can easily find the correct location using the ‘[rappdirs](https://github.com/r-lib/rappdirs)’ package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! `rappdirs` looks promising. Re: sharing configurations, I don't make those decisions, I'm just asked to "make it work"  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Whether this is the "right" thing to do or not, the actual code appears fine to me. I'd just add some debugging to the `paths.R` script to confirm that things look the way you expect them to.